# ESP32, enabling external 32kHz crystal

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I'm having the damnedest time finding reliable docs on using an external quartz 32khz crystal with my esp32 project. I'm using ESP-IDF.

My external 32khz crystal is hooked up to IO32 and IO33 (those should be the right pins).

I'm currently using ESP-IDF 4.4.3.

I've gone in through `menuconfig` and turned on everything I can think to turn on. Here are the changes I made...

```
======== The settings changes I made in menuconfig ========

The `>` notation shows how I navigated the menus.

> Component Config
  > ESP32-specific
    > RTC clock source
      * set to `External 32kHz crystal`

> Component Config
  > ESP32-specific
    > Additional current for external 32kHz crystal
      * left at `none`

> Component Config
  > Bluetooth
    * Enable Bluetooth

> Component Config
  > Bluetooth
    > Bluetooth controller
      > MODEM SLEEP Options
        > Bluetooth low power clock
          * set to `External 32kHz crystal`

> Component Config
  > Bluetooth
    > Bluetooth Host
      * select `nimBLE - BLE only`
```

And still I'm getting no oscillation signal when I look at the crystal with an oscilloscope.

Is there anything I need to do in C++ to enable my external 32khz crystal? To initialize it? To set the pins up correctly to use the crystal? The docs only talk about settings changes in menuconfig, I don't see any code I'm supposed to employ.

Do you see anything I'm missing?

==============

In response to `hcheung` below, here's a schematic of our quartz setup...

[image: quartz crystal schematic]

Comment: I've also been looking at the logs that are dumped into the serial monitor when the device is booted.

I'm expecting to see the log message `waiting for 32k oscillator to start up` from the file `clk.c` in the ESP-IDF. But I don't get that message.

Comment: Which ESP are you using? Dev-Board or custom pcb?

Comment: `My external 32khz crystal is hooked up to IO32 and IO33 (those should be the right pins)`, sounds like you added a crystal yourself, did you read the [Hardware Design Guideline](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf) regarding RTC crystal with the correct load capacitance values and bias resistor? what is the load capacitance value of your crystal that you purchased?

Comment: @hcheung, I posted the schematic above.

Comment: @sebo1234, it's a custom PCB.

The crystal and capacitors are placed right next to the pads where IO32/IO33 contact the PCB.

Comment: We're using a crystal with a 12.5pF loading capacitance and a spec of 70k-ohm max ESR. We estimated the stray capacitance of the PCB and came up with 18pF for input capacitors. We're using the ESP32-WROOM-32, and according to the design guidelines should not need a bias resistor for that module. This is the first time we're trying to bring up the RTC and part of this is intended to tune the circuit as we don't know the actual as-built PCB stray capacitance. I would guess 18pF is close enough to get it running and we could adjust it up or down slightly based on in circuit measurements.

Comment: The second outstanding questions on our end is weather or not ESP-IDF/clk.c is even trying to start the RTC?